# Obtener la ultima columna horizontal de una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

tengo una tabla en HTML y PHP donde quisiera obtener la ultima **columna completa** de mi tabla, con su titulo y todos sus datos hacia abajo.

Esa es mi representación de mi tabla completa en EXCEL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el resultado final, obteniendo la ultima Columna completa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté con este código en JS pero no funcionó

```
function Ver() {
var rows = document.getElementById('tablaid').getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = function() {
    var result = this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
        alert(result);
    }
}
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2):

Pudes usar el selector `last-child`, asi:

```js
const ultima_columna= document.querySelectorAll("#tabla td:last-child");

console.log([...ultima_columna].map(e=>e.innerText));
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

El selector está diciendo, selecciona todos los útimos hijos tipo "td" del padre "#tabla", podría ser también "#tabla tr td:last-child".